# Error when using update between two tables joined by a code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Be the following python pandas DataFrame:

| ID | country | money | code | money_add | other | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 832932 | Other | NaN | 00000 | NaN | [N2,N2,N4] | 0 days 01:37:00 |
| 217#8# | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | [N1,N2,N3] | 2 days 01:01:00 |
| 1329T2 | France | 12131 | 00020 | 3452 | [N1,N1] | 1 days 03:55:00 |
| 124932 | France | NaN | 00016 | NaN | [N2] | 0 days 01:28:00 |
| 194022 | France | NaN | 00000 | NaN | [N4,N3] | 3 days 02:35:00 |

If `code` column is not `NaN` and the `money` column is `NaN`, we update the values `money` and `money_add` from the following table. Using the `code` and `cod_t` columns as a key.

| cod_t | money | money_add |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000 | 4532 | 72323 |
| 00016 | 1213 | 23822 |
| 00030 | 1313 | 8393 |
| 00020 | 1813 | 27328 |

Example of the resulting table:

| ID | country | money | code | money_add | other | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 832932 | Other | 4532 | 00000 | 72323 | [N2,N2,N4] | 0 days 01:37:00 |
| 217#8# | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | [N1,N2,N3] | 2 days 01:01:00 |
| 1329T2 | France | 12131 | 00020 | 3452 | [N1,N1] | 1 days 03:55:00 |
| 124932 | France | 1213 | 00016 | 23822 | [N2] | 0 days 01:28:00 |
| 194022 | France | 4532 | 00000 | 72323 | [N4,N3] | 3 days 02:35:00 |

User @jezrael, gave me the following solution to the problem:

```py
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('cod_t').set_index('cod_t')
df = df.set_index(df['code'])
df.update(df1, overwrite=False)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

But this code gives me an error that I don't know how to solve:

```
TypeError: The DType <class 'numpy.dtype[timedelta64]'> could not be promoted by <class
'numpy.dtype[float64]'>. This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. 
For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. 
The full list of DTypes is: (<class 'numpy.dtype[timedelta64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>)
```

```
// First DataFrame dtypes
ID                                 object
country                            object
code                               object
money                             float64
money_add                         float64
other                              object
time                      timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
// Second DataFrame dtypes
cod_t                     object
money                      int64
money_add                  int64
dtype: object
```

I would be grateful if you could help me to solve the error, or suggest an alternative method to using `update`.

Comment: If you provide the code to produce your two input dataframes, it would make it much easier for answerers.

Comment: @Carola do you mind sharing the output for `.dtypes` of each dataframe? It would be something like `print(df.dtypes)`.

Comment: Looks like the question you asked previously did not have the time column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) not working well here is alternative - first use left join for new columns from second DataFrame by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2 = df.merge(df1.drop_duplicates('cod_t').rename(columns={'cod_t':'code'}), 
               on='code', 
               how='left',
               suffixes=('','_'))

print (df2)
       ID country    money  code  money_add         other            time  \
0  832932   Other      NaN   0.0        NaN  [N2, N2, N4] 0 days 01:37:00   
1  217#8#     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  [N1, N2, N3] 2 days 01:01:00   
2  1329T2  France  12131.0  20.0     3452.0      [N1, N1] 1 days 03:55:00   
3  124932  France      NaN  16.0        NaN          [N2] 0 days 01:28:00   
4  194022  France      NaN   0.0        NaN      [N4, N3] 3 days 02:35:00   

   money_  money_add_  
0  4532.0     72323.0  
1     NaN         NaN  
2  1813.0     27328.0  
3  1213.0     23822.0  
4  4532.0     72323.0
```

Then get columns names with/without `_`:

```
cols_with_ = df2.columns[df2.columns.str.endswith('_')]
cols_without_ = cols_with_.str.rstrip('_')

print (cols_with_)
Index(['money_', 'money_add_'], dtype='object')

print (cols_without_)
Index(['money', 'money_add'], dtype='object')
```

Pass to [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and last remove helper columns:

```
df2[cols_without_] = (df2[cols_without_].combine_first(df2[cols_with_]
                                        .rename(columns=lambda x: x.rstrip('_'))))
df2 = df2.drop(cols_with_, axis=1)
print (df2)
       ID country    money  code  money_add         other            time
0  832932   Other   4532.0   0.0    72323.0  [N2, N2, N4] 0 days 01:37:00
1  217#8#     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  [N1, N2, N3] 2 days 01:01:00
2  1329T2  France  12131.0  20.0     3452.0      [N1, N1] 1 days 03:55:00
3  124932  France   1213.0  16.0    23822.0          [N2] 0 days 01:28:00
4  194022  France   4532.0   0.0    72323.0      [N4, N3] 3 days 02:35:00
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another method different from Jezrael's, but you can try it out.

You can first create a condition variable for your dataframe.

```
condition = (df.code.isin(df1.cod_t) & ~df.code.isnull() & df.money.isna())
columns = ['money', 'money_add']
```

Next, use `df.loc` to do the update.

```
df.loc[condition, columns] = df1.loc[condition, columns]

       ID country    money  code  money_add       other            time
0  832932   Other   4532.0   0.0    72323.0  [N2,N2,N4] 0 days 01:37:00
1  217#8#     NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN  [N1,N2,N3] 2 days 01:01:00
2  1329T2  France  12131.0  20.0     3452.0     [N1,N1] 1 days 03:55:00
3  124932  France   1813.0  16.0    27328.0        [N2] 0 days 01:28:00
4  194022  France   8932.0   0.0     3204.0     [N4,N3] 3 days 02:35:00
```

### Update

If there's an unequal length for both dataframe.

```
df1_cond = df1.cod_t.isin(df.loc[condition].code)

result = [i[1:] for row in df.loc[condition].code for i in df1.loc[df1_cond].values if row in i]

df.loc[condition, columns] = result
```

Comment: ```df.loc[condition, columns] = df1.loc[condition, columns]``` get next error: ```IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).```

Comment: ```df1.loc[condition, columns]``` is the main problem

Comment: no, are normal columns

Comment: I removed a row from df1 that might cause confusion.

Comment: I have updated it, will this be ok for you?